# Creating random UIDs for new models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a Rails 5.2 app.
This is a multi tenant saas app. To make it more "secure" I don't want to use the incremental ids of the database to present on the frontend. Therefore I create a helper method to generate random IDs.

Is this a bad idea? What are the weaknesses?

This is my code:

```
module Uidable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do

    before_create :generate_random_id

    def generate_random_id
      begin
        self.id = SecureRandom.random_number(1_000_000_000)
      end while self.class.name.constantize.where(id: self.id).exists?
    end 

  end

end
```

Comment: This is a bit of a wide-open question, but replacing integer IDs is entirely doable and can be a good idea depending on the use case. I suggest you look at using UUIDs instead of rolling your own integers, as you will pretty quickly collide IDs. If you use Postgres, you can take advantage of its built-in UUID primary key support. There are side effects (`.first` and `.last` give unexpected results pre-Rails 6) to be aware of; there's quite a few articles around that cover how to migrate and deal with the side effects.

Comment: I want to find a way to obfuscate IDs in my app, that is the use case. I am ok with .first and .last issues.

Comment: Probably the easiest solution is to use https://github.com/norman/friendly_id. Leave the id as is to avoid useless headaches. Or, use a new column to store that uuid.